# Which field can I use to capture a string in Twilio Autopilot. Twilio.ALPHANUMERIC does not work

Tags: twilio

I want to collect a portion of the message as a string that can contain a combination of letters(upper/lower), numbers, dashes, spaces, slashes and I cannot define all the possible values in a Custom Field because they are dynamic. This string can be:

```
1. AFCON 2020
2. England
3. FIFA WC 2016
```

etc.

I have tried using `TWILIO.ALPHANUMERIC` but it cuts out other parts or it returns first letter only. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you already found the list of Twilio's built-in field types [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/built-in-field-types). If none of the built-in's work for you you have two options:

**A)** Don't provide a type, if you don't provide a type then free-form input will be collected. See the [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/actions/collect#question-properties).

**B)** Use a custom field type. If you have only a selected number of options then this should be your choice.

For **B)** you could specify this as:

```
"fieldTypes": [
    {
        "uniqueName": "Custom.SELECTIONS",
        "values": [
            {
                "language": "en-US",
                "value" : "AFCON 2020",
                "synonymOf" : null
            },
            {
                "language": "en-US",
                "value" : "England",
                "synonymOf" : null
            },
            {
                "language": "en-US",
                "value" : "FIFA WC 2016",
                "synonymOf" : null
            },
            ...
        ]
    }
]
```

You would use this then as `"type": "Custom.SELECTIONS"`

Comment: Also, validate webhook, as discussed here - https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/actions/collect#validate. `A webhook to validate the value being collected. Useful when validating fields like order numbers or available dates that can only be validated against your business logic`

Comment: Thanks for the addition @Alan ! Indeed the webhook for validation can come in really handy here when working with free-form input for example.

Comment: Thanks man. This is exactly what I wanted and more. The tutorials I was using from the blog were not mentioning Collect.